# Creating 4 SQL queries on a set of data for healthcare, called the Four-Cut Methodology

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 70+ thousand rows that's similar to the following data,

```
id | patient |  date    | provider
________________________________
1  |   bob   | 2020-2-1 | dr joe
1  |   bob   | 2020-1-1 | dr joe

2  |   tom   | 2020-4-1 | dr ann
2  |   tom   | 2020-3-1 | dr joe
2  |   tom   | 2020-2-1 | dr joe

3  |   jan   | 2020-6-1 | dr ann
3  |   jan   | 2020-5-1 | dr ann
3  |   jan   | 2020-4-1 | dr joe
3  |   jan   | 2020-3-1 | dr joe

4  |   ken   | 2020-6-1 | dr ted
4  |   ken   | 2020-5-1 | dr ann
4  |   ken   | 2020-4-1 | dr joe
```

And I need to pull the following reports from the data,

1. Patients who have seen only one provider in the past year. (example, id 1)
2. Patients who have seen multiple providers, but one provider the majority of the time in past year. (example, id 2)
3. Patients who have seen two or more providers equally in the past year (No majority provider can be determined). (example, id 3)
4. Patients who have seen multiple providers. (example, id 4)

I'm using MySQL and it's been awhile since I've used SQL and I was hoping for some suggestions on how I can pull the specific data out of the table.

Here is a [document explaining](https://www.careinnovations.org/wp-content/uploads/4.-Empanelment-Four-Cut-Methodology_CP3-Toolkit-2.pdf) the desired data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, but you can use two levels of aggregation with window functions:

```
select patient,
       (case when max_cnt = total_cnt then 'One provider'
             when max_cnt > 0.5 * total_cnt then 'One dominant provider'
             when avg_cnt = max_cnt then 'Multiple equal'
             else 'Two or more'
        end) as grouping
from (select patient, provider, count(*) as cnt,
             avg(count(*)) over (partition by patient) as avg_cnt,
             max(count(*)) over (partition by patient) as max_cnt,
             sum(count(*)) over (partition by patient) as total_cnt
      from t
      where date > curdate - interval 1 year
      group by pateint, provider
     ) pp
group by patient;
```

EDIT:

For patients who have only seen one provide, just use aggregation:

```
select patient
from t
group by patient
having max(provider) = min(provider);
```

You can have a `where` clause to limit the time frame if you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I'm still struggling. If possible, would you post how to find just, "Patients who have seen only one provider"? The result would just be patient "bob".

Comment: Thank you so much, worked perfectly! I figure it can't hurt to ask, any assistance with report 2 and 3 would be much appreciated. I removed all old entries from the table, so date/time no longer matter. For example, "Patients who have seen multiple providers, but one provider the majority of the time."

Comment: @FHC . . . A question should be limited to a single question.  The original answer actually addresses all four.